# typeorm/postresql - Create a query that groups by column, aggregates another column and get relations for aggregated array

Tags: typescript, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions, typeorm

I have two tables in the database with a one-to-many relation. The schema looks like this:

```
types
-------------------------------
| id | brand      | type      |
-------------------------------
| 1  | Ford       | City car  |
-------------------------------
| 2  | Volkswagen | SUV       |
-------------------------------
| 3  | Ford       | SUV       |
-------------------------------
| 4  | Volkswagen | City car  |
-------------------------------

models
--------------------------
| id | type_id | model   |
--------------------------
| 1  | 4       | UP!     |
--------------------------
| 2  | 1       | Fiesta  |
--------------------------
| 3  | 2       | Tiguan  |
--------------------------
| 4  | 2       | Touareg |
--------------------------
| 5  | 3       | Kuga    |
--------------------------
```

What I'm trying to obtain is a json with a structure that looks like this:

```json
[{
   "type": "City car",
   "brands": [{
      "Ford": [
         { "model": "Fiesta" }
      ],
      "Volkswagen": [
         { "model": "UP!" }
      ],
   }]
},
{
   "type": "SUV",
   "brands": [{
      "Ford": [
         { "model": "Kuga" }
      ],
      "Volkswagen": [
         { "model": "Touareg" },
         { "model": "Tiguan"  },
      ],
   }]
}]
```

Pratically what I am trying to do is to group the records by the `type` column, aggregate in an array all the different brands of the same type and then for each type+brand combination get the different models.

I'm using `postgresql` with `typeorm`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query to Postgresql (I tested it in Postgresql version 13):

```
SELECT  
    json_agg(types::jsonb || brands::jsonb)
   
FROM (

    SELECT 
        json_build_object('type', "type") AS types,
        json_build_object('brands', json_object_agg(key, value)) AS brands

    FROM (

        SELECT 
            "type",
            json_build_object(brand, json_object_agg(key, value)) AS brands

        FROM 

            (SELECT 
                t."type", 
                t.brand, json_build_object('model', json_agg(m.model)) AS models
            FROM types t 
            INNER JOIN models m ON t.id = m.type_id
            GROUP BY t."type", t.brand) AS a, json_each(models)

        GROUP BY "type", brand) b, json_each(brands)

    GROUP BY "type") c
```

Result:

```
[{"type": "SUV", "brands": {"Ford": {"model": ["Kuga"]}, "Volkswagen": {"model": ["Tiguan", "Touareg"]}}}, {"type": "City car", "brands": {"Ford": {"model": ["Fiesta"]}, "Volkswagen": {"model": ["UP!"]}}}]
```